# Are those two models equals?

Tags: regression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R-squared: X “explains” the percentage of variation of the Y values. Does axis order matter?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18434/r-squared-x-explains-the-percentage-of-variation-of-the-y-values-does-axis-o)

Excuse me about the strange question but I have a doubt regarding the linear regression. 
Take a look at the code below:

```
  x = rnorm(100)
  y = rnorm(100)

  mod1 = lm(x~y+0)
  mod2 = lm(y~x+0)
```

As You can see I change the regressand and the regressors on those two linear models.
My question regarding the residuals of those two models, why they should be different if I use the same variables?

Comment: Answered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18448.

Comment: There's a good answer at the above link. It may also help you to read my answer here: [what-is-the-difference-between-doing-linear-regression-on-y-with-x-versus-x-with-y?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22718/22721#22721), which is explained conceptually / graphically instead of mathematically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the two models are not the same. In linear regression you are trying to find the best fit line that minimizes the squared difference between the actual $y$ values and the estimates that result from assuming that $y$ can be approximated by $x\beta$.

To see how the above translates into a graphical picture- imagine that traditional plot of $y$ vs $x$ (i.e., $y$ values are plotted on the Y-axis against $x$ values on the X-axis). Using the above graph as a visual aid, we can see that linear regression of $y=x\beta + \epsilon$ amounts to minimizing the *vertical* error between the estimate provided by line and the actual value we have at hand.

In contrast, the linear regression of $x=y\alpha+\epsilon$ (i.e., when you switch the role of $x$ and $y$) amounts to minimizing the *horizontal* error between the estimate provided by the line and the actual value at hand.

Thus, in general we get different slopes (i.e., different lines) and hence different residuals.